# convert an empty string to datetime

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a field in a SQL Server database that is of type string.  This field is used for different things for different clients.  We are storing dates in this field for one client.  When the field is not loaded with anything it is empty (empty string).  I need to extract the data from this field for this one client and use it in my where statement.  I thought it would be a simple matter of casting the value to date datatype, but am getting the error

‘Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Here is the snippet of code:  `where boldet.detmisc1 >= @begin`.
I have tried the following:

`where cast(boldet.detmisc1 as date) >= @begin`

`where cast(isnull(nullif(boldet.detmisc1, ''), ‘’) as date) >= @begin`

Is there any way to convert an empty string value to a null datetime value so that I can use it in my where statement?

Database: SQL Server 2012

I am attaching the entire query in the event that something else is causing the error:

```
    declare @begin datetime
set @begin = dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
declare @stop datetime
set @stop = dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
;
 with a as (select boldet.BOL_Key
 --boldet.DetMisc1

from ProBillTBL pro WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN BOLTBL bol WITH (NOLOCK) On Pro.ProBill_Key = Bol.ProBill_Key
    INNER JOIN BOLDetailTBL boldet WITH (NOLOCK) On Bol.BOL_Key = BolDet.BOL_Key
    INNER JOIN ClientLocTBL cliloc WITH (NOLOCK) On Pro.ClientLoc_Key = Cliloc.ClientLoc_Key
    INNER JOIN CarrierTBL car WITH (NOLOCK) On Pro.Carrier_Key = Car.Carrier_Key
    --left outer join support sup (nolock) on pro.probill_key = sup.probill_key     

where cliloc.ClientLoc_Key = 2519
    and boldet.DetMisc3 in ('1', '4', '5')
     and (pro.ProEnteredDate >= @begin)

     or (cast((case when boldet.detmisc1 = '' then NULL else boldet.detmisc1 end) as date) >= @begin))


select * from a
```

When I comment out this section `(cast((case when boldet.detmisc1 = '' then NULL else boldet.detmisc1 end) as date) >= @begin)` I get a result, but with that in the where clause I get the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE 
  CAST((CASE WHEN boldet.detmisc1 = '' THEN NULL ELSE boldet.detmisc1 END) 
  As Date) >= @begin
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error.  I edited my post to include the entire query.

Comment: Maybe it is not just empty string but other invalid date values.

Comment: Magnus, my first reaction was 'No, that is probably not it." However, I did check and found 2 values in the field that were invalid entries.  Thank you for prompting me to check (something I should have already done).

Comment: Although the above answer provided by Magnus helped in some cases, I was still having issues with converting text to EXCEL.  I finally settled on using Regular Expressions to look for a format like 'mm/dd/yyyy'.  The one issue I have with this method is that the user is restricted to that format to enter dates.  I have provided training on this and it has been running now for 2 months with no further problems.